# My method to check if word is in a string of letters never returns true

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a word wheel solver, and it's working properly in python, but I cannot port it over to Java / Android. It returns nothing, that's to say, the end set of valid words is always empty.

The files are in assets/dictionary.

I can print out each line of the dictionary files to the log, no problem, but actually checking if they contain certain optional and required letters is where I'm stuck.

The dictionary files are divided by letter to save time.

**The java file**

```
 for(String letter : allLettersSet) {
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("dictionary/" + letter.toLowerCase() + ".txt")));
                Log.d("myTag", "opening " + "dictionary/" + letter.toLowerCase() + ".txt");
                String line;
                line = reader.readLine();
                while (line != null) {
//                    Log.d("myTag",line);
                    if(checkLetters(line.toUpperCase(), optionalLetters, requiredLetters)) {
                        validWordsList.add(line);
                    }else{
//                        Log.d("myTag", "Returned False...");
                    }
                }
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        Log.d("myTag","Valid words are -> " + validWordsList);

    }


public boolean checkLetters(String word, ArrayList<String> optionalList, ArrayList<String> requiredList) {

        ArrayList<String> optionalListEditable = new ArrayList<>(optionalList);
        ArrayList<String> requiredListEditable = new ArrayList<>(requiredList);
        ArrayList<String> wordListEditable = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(word));
        ArrayList<String> requiredListEditable2 = new ArrayList<>(requiredList);


        for(String letter : wordListEditable) {

            if (optionalListEditable.contains(letter)) {
                optionalListEditable.remove(letter);

            } else if (requiredListEditable.contains(letter)) {
                requiredListEditable.remove(letter);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        for(String letter : requiredListEditable2) {
            if (word.contains(letter)) {
                requiredListEditable2.remove(letter);
            }else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

The allLettersSet is just a set of all the letters in this particular run. The letters that the user submits are always uppercase, So I made each line from the bufferedReader uppercase so there would be no case issues.

The function always seems to return false. It never returns true, unless I flip the purpose of the function to see what words DON'T match. Then it adds about 50 words to the array List and stops. I'm concerned it may be the iterating stopping prematurely, but The Log shows that it iterates over all the possible letter files.

Comment: `Arrays.asList(word)` returns a List containing `word` as a single entry.  So, for example, if your word was "Java", `Arrays.asList(word)` would return a new List that looks like this:  `["Java"]`.  It **won't** return a list containing `["J", "a", "v", "a"]`.  This means that when you do `for(String letter : wordListEditable)`, you're not looping through the letters of the word "Java".  You're looping through a list of Strings where the only entry is the entire word "Java".  And clearly `optionalListEditable.contains("Java")` will never be true.

Comment: I agree with Jordan's comment above. For your case, you could try Arrays.asList(word.split("")) and I think that may work. However, you should look for alternative options like character array or char array as they may be more optimized methods than comparing strings of a single character.

Comment: @Jordan and when converting the words to arrays this way, it works, however the program still does not work, because, due to the logcat, it's seen that there's an empty string at position 0 of each word : for example [, A, C, U, P, U, N, C, T, U, R, E]. How can this be mitigated and could it be just the hidden 'enter' character at the end of each line?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it to work by using a substring which excluded the first item in the list.